# sound notifications on minimized browsertabs

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

My problem is that I can't get my notifications working correctly when browsertabs are minimized.
There is a timer, that should give a pingsound when finished, but the timer runs out, opdates data base correctly, but the ping sound only plays when I maximize the browser again.
It works fine, when the browser is open and just displaying other tabs.
Is there some special thing I need to write to get it working when hidden?

Its a client side app, build in flutter BTW. with firebase Data bases and hosting

I guess I just expected it work?